# JavaScript cant remove character at end of string

Tags: javascript, string

This is for something else, but I put together an example to show this problem.
Note: I want to remove all occurrences of "o", an coincidentally it seemed to look like i wanted to remove only the character at the end of the string - i thought there was a bug with not being able to remove the last character (and that `replace` replaced all occurrences).

```
var s = "hollo";
console.log(s);
s = s.replace("o", "");
console.log(s)
```

This happens on Chrome and Firefox which are the only browsers I've tested it with.

I get this in the console

```
hollo
hllo
```

Why does it do this?

Edit: This seems to fix the problem:

```
if (s.lastIndexOf("o") != -1) s = s.substr(0, s.length - 1);
```

But I still want to know why exactly this happens.

Comment: my problem was i thought that the replace couldn't find a character at the end of the string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `replace` only removes the first match it sees. To remove all occurrences, use a regular expression instead. This one removes "o" globally (g) regardless of case (i).

```
s = s.replace(/o/gi,'');
```

Test this in the console and it should give you "hll":

```
'hollo'.replace(/o/gi,'');
```

Comment: Can you add how to remove this character *at the end of the string*, as the OP's title states?

Comment: @Jongware I think you missed the OP's point. He seems to want to remove all o's in the string, but can't remove the last one (the second one in fact) via `remove`.

Comment: Ah right. The suggested "fix" at the end threw me off.

Comment: (After futher rumination) The OP suggests "`replace` has a problem with the *last* character in a string". However, using the same input `hollo` and removing the `l` will show it's not related to the *position*.

Comment: Joseph is right, replace(string, string) only removes the first occurrence. Note that firefox has an optional third argument for that case: replace(string, string, flags), where you can add "g" for global. This is not supported in chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

I am undesratnd that you want to remove all 'o' from the string. You can also create prototy for same. you want to use like 's.ReplaceAll("o","")'.

```
function ReplaceAll(str,oldchar,newchar)
{

    if(str.indexOf(oldchar) != -1)
    {
        str = str.replace(oldchar, newchar);
        str = ReplaceAll(str,oldchar,newchar);
    }
    else
    {
        return str;
    }
}

var s = "hollo";
s = ReplaceAll(s,"o", "");
```

Let me know if i am not understand your requirement.

Comment: Thanks but the answer above was first and explained it clearly too